# Lego Mind storms file type conversion

Tags: file-type, lego-mindstorms

I have some Lego mind storms files on my PC `(.ev3)` and i want to convert them to work on my iPad `(.ev3M)` does anyone know how to do this? i have looked all over and turned here as my final attempt.

Answer (score 0):

I have contacted Lego support and found out there’s no way to do it.